# react-router-dom not working when change path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to render component Home and About using `react-router` but I get nothing. I think the problem in the index file with the store. How I can fix it?

Here is a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-matsumoto-p49zlp?file=/src/App.js).

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import Store from "./Store";

const root = reactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <Store>
    <App />
  </Store>
);
```

Store

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react'
import Layout from './Layout'

export const Data = createContext()


function Store({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true)
  const  value = {state, setState}

  return (
    <Data.Provider value={value}>
      <Layout>{children}</Layout>
    </Data.Provider>
  )
}

export default Store
```

Layout

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Data } from "./Store";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Routes,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

function Layout({ children }) {
  const { state } = useContext(Data);
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Router>
        <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>        </div>
        <div className={`${state ? "hide" : "show"} mobil `}>
          <div className="children">{children} </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

App

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store component should receive the children props and pass it down to the Layout, ex:

```
function Store({children}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true)
  const  value = {state, setState}

  return (
    <Data.Provider value={value}>
      <Layout>{children}</Layout>
    </Data.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Also, you should have only one BrowserRouter, either in Layout or App, not both

Comment: but is rendered two check here https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-matsumoto-p49zlp?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You Had two `<Layout>` components called, one in the <Store>, and one in the `<App>` once you remove the one in the Store, it should work fine

Comment: leaving the children only of course in the Store, so It should look like: 
`return <Data.Provider value={value}>{children}</Data.Provider>;`

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to see your [`Layout.js`](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-matsumoto-p49zlp?file=/src/Layout.js) file.

```js
function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <!-- Router -->
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <div>{children}</div>
      <!-- /Router -->
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can't use `<Router>` because the `Layout` is being recursively used and implicitly you're nesting the `<Router>` element. It's better to use the element only once in your App before it loads.

Comment: Why can't a `Router` be used there? If there is no router there then how will the links and wrapped routes (*via `children` prop*) function? The issue is that there are ***two*** `Layout` components rendered, one within the other, and it's the nested `Layout` (*with nested `Router`*) that is the issue. If you remove `Router` here you remove it from both `Layout` instances and the app will still need to render a `Router` *somewhere*.

Comment: @DrewReese It's supposed to be `Route` and not `Router` - This one's a one time use for the whole app, encompassing the layout as well. See `BrowserRouter as Router`? They're already there. This router is nested. Please check that there's a Router in the higher level in the `app.js`. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @DrewReese See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289840/react-router-dom-not-working-when-change-path/72289913?noredirect=1#comment127713478_72289901).

Comment: Ok, what is your point? See my answer that explains exactly the issue with the duplicate nested `Layout` component and not the `Router`.

Comment: @DrewReese I guess I understood. Let me correct my answer. Sorry, I was overlooking something and felt it right. Apologies. Thanks for clarifying. Also, the OP has then changed the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The code you have shared is rendering a `Layout` component within another `Layout` component. The `Layout` component is rendering a `Router`. It is an invariant violation to render a router within another router.

```
function Layout({ children }) {
  const { state } = useContext(Data);
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Router> // <-- nested router!!
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>{" "}
        </div>
        <div className={`${state ? "hide" : "show"} mobil `}>
          <div className="children">{children} </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Both the `Store` and `App` components are rendering a `Layout` component and `Store` is directly rendering `App`.

## Solution

Remove one or the other `Layout` component from either `Store` or `App`. I suggest removing it from `Store` so `Store` is ***only*** providing the context value and not mixing in other UI layout and routing context concerns. `Store` should render the `Provider` and `children` prop.

Example:

```
function Store({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const value = { state, setState };

  return (
    <Data.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </Data.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-not-working-whene-change-path]